# All-in-one USB-C Dock for 2016 15" Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware

I frequently need to plug the following into my 15" touchbar MacBook Pro:

- External monitor (2560x1440@60hz)
- USB Mouse
- USB Keyboard
- Power (something in the 60W+ range - not 15W)

Currently all the adapters needed to do that are turning my desk into a rat's nest and I'd rather not plug 3 separate things in every time I set my laptop down.

I've looked around and can't find anything that fits the requirements. Anyone know of something that fits the bill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a USB-C/Thunderbolt 3 dock. One cord connects all the peripherals you ask for to your Mac.

OWC makes several, StarTech makes several, Belkin makes amazing one - http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U095-APL/

Be sure you know if you're getting one that charges your Mac - they cost a little more, but should be much more stable for video / power and save your Apple adapter to sit in your go bag or the second place you plug in.

If you want a bargain - you could get a ThunderBolt 2 adapter, but then you still need a power cord and also the cost of TB-3 to TB-2 adapter. Probably not cheaper based on the prices I see today for docks.

Comment: Thanks! That fits the bill perfectly (although damn that's pricey! You could buy an iPad for the cost of that thing).